# What is CALLBACK_URL to Obtain a request token from JIRA?

Tags: oauth, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

I am trying to perform OAuth authentication for JIRA. And I got stuck at [step-1](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-oauth-authentication) only where it said like:

> **1. Obtain a request token from JIRA**
>
> Execute this command:
>
> ```
> java -jar rest-oauth-client-1.0.one-jar.jar requestToken JIRA_BASE_URL CALLBACK_URL
> ```
>
> Replace JIRA_BASE_URL with the URL to your JIRA instance 
>   and replace CALLBACK_URL with the URL that should be called after the user has authorized the OAuth request token.

Here I am not getting what is `CALLBACK_URL`

Can you please tell me what should be the value of CALLBACK_URL

My JIRA instance is: https://chandanjira.atlassian.net